# Zip all array values of hash

Tags: ruby

I'd like to zip all the array values of a hash. I know there's a way to zip arrays together. I'd like to do that with the values of my hash below.

```
current_hash = {:a=>["k", "r", "u"],
                :b=>["e", " ", "l"],
                :c=>["d", "o", "w"],
                :d=>["e", "h"]
                }

 desired_outcome = "keder ohulw"
```

I have included my desired outcome above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
current_hash.values.then { |first, *rest| first.zip(*rest) }.flatten.compact.join
```

An unfortunate thing with Ruby `zip` is that the first enumerable needs to be the receiver, and the others need to be parameters. Here, I use `then`, parameter deconstruction and splat to separate the first enumerable from the rest. `flatten` gets rid of the column arrays, `compact` gets rid of the `nil` (though it's not really necessary as `join` will ignore it), and `join` turns the array into the string.

---

Note that Ruby `zip` will stop at length of the receiver; so if `:a` is shorter than the others, you will likely have a surprising result. If that is a concern, please update with an example that reflects that scenario, and the desired outcome.

Comment: Eh. `current_hash.values.reduce(&:zip).join #⇒ "keder ohulw"`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Nice. I guess I'm guilty of premature optimisation... :P

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm fleshing out @Amadan's remark below the horizontal line in is answer. Suppose:

```
current_hash = { a:["k","r"], b:["e"," ","l"], c:["d","o","w"], d:["e", "h"] }
```

and you wished to return `"keder ohlw"`. If you made `["k","r"]` and `[["e"," ","l"], ["d","o","w"], ["e", "h"]]` `zip`'s receiver and argument, respectively, you would get `"keder oh"`, which omits `"l"` and `"w"`. (See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-zip), especially the 3<sup>rd</sup> paragraph.)

To include those strings you would need to fill out `["k","r"]` with `nil`s to make it as long as the longest value, or make `zip`'s receiver an array of `nil`s of the same length. The latter approach can be implemented as follows:

```
vals = current_hash.values
  #=> [["k", "r"], ["e", " ", "l"], ["d", "o", "w"], ["e", "h"]] 
([nil]*vals.map(&:size).max).zip(*vals).flatten.compact.join
  #=> "keder ohlw"
```

Note:

```
a = [nil]*vals.map(&:size).max
  #=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

and

```
a.zip(*vals)
  #=> [[nil, "k", "e", "d", "e"],
  #    [nil, "r", " ", "o", "h"],
  #    [nil, nil, "l", "w", nil]]
```

One could alternatively use [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) rather than `zip`.

```
vals = current_hash.values
idx = (0..vals.map(&:size).max-1).to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
vals.map { |a| a.values_at(*idx) }.transpose.flatten.compact.join
  #=> "keder ohlw"
```

See [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at). Note:

```
a = vals.map { |a| a.values_at(*idx) }
  #=> [["k", "r", nil],
  #    ["e", " ", "l"],
  #    ["d", "o", "w"],
  #    ["e", "h", nil]] 
a.transpose
  #=> [["k", "e", "d", "e"],
  #    ["r", " ", "o", "h"],
  #    [nil, "l", "w", nil]]
```